How do I lookup sheet names and create hyperlinks to sheets in a workbook?
I am managing a workbook with many sheets and I would like to make a separate sheet for navigation.
The sheets' names have a numeric prefix, like:
000-ATable
001-AnotherTable
002-YetAnotherTable
The sheet names may be subject to changes, so I'd like to use a formula.
What I want:



Number
Link




000
ATable(links to 000-ATable)


001
AnotherTable(links to 001-AnotherTable)


002
YetAnotherTable(links to 002-YetAnotherTable)


003
(returns blank if sheet with such prefix does not exist)


...




How do I do this?

Does How To Generate A List Of Sheet Names From A Workbook Without VBA | How To Excel answer you question?

Or 3 Methods to Create a List of Hyperlinks to All Worksheets in an Excel Workbook

So, here is way using Excel Macro 4.0 and with the help of dynamic functions, note that HYPERLINK() will not work with SPILL.


First, need to create a defined names to automatically grab the SHEETNAMES therefore, jump onto Formulas Tab, click on Name Manager and click New, process with the Name as SHEETNAMES and use in refers to :
=TEXTAFTER(GET.WORKBOOK(1),"[")


• Formula used in cell B2
=LET(
     _SheetNames, "["&INDEX(SHEETNAMES,ROWS(A$1:A2)),
     IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(_SheetNames,"]"),"-"),""))


• Formula used in cell C2
=LET(
     _SheetNames, "["&INDEX(SHEETNAMES,ROWS(A$1:A2)),
IFERROR(HYPERLINK("#'"&_SheetNames&"'!A1",TEXTAFTER(_SheetNames,"-")),""))


Both the above formulas needs to be filled down as well as the workbook needs to be saved as .xlsm or .xlsb

Here is a link one can check



Alternatively, one can get Number as in context of the OP by using SHEETS() function:
=BASE(SEQUENCE(SHEETS()-1,,0),10,3)


